# Passing and returning 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters, computer-science

I have not coded in C much at all so I am having difficulty's with pointers for a 2D array. I have a 2D array 3x3 of type integer.

Here is my method I am trying to use:

```
 void addMoveToBoard(int *gameArray[3][3], int a, int b, int player) {
        *((int *)gameArray + x * 3 + y) = player;
        if (a == 0) {
            mvaddch(a, b, 'X');
        }
    ...
    }
```

And here is my main:

```
int *board[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
addMoveToBoard(board, 0, 0, 1);
```

First issue is when I pass the zero's for the 2nd and 3rd parameters, they are not 0 when I use them in the function. When using mvaddch(a,b, 'X') it appears as though a and b are 1 instead of 0. Also am I correctly assigning a value to a element in game array?

Comment: `int *board[3][3]` declares an array of three arrays of three *pointers*. I suspect that isn't what you want.

Comment: Please show real code. And show it as an [MCVE]. Your code references variables that are not defined such as `x` and `y` and your question references code such as `mvaddch` which is not even shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function signature to be without the `*`:

```
void addMoveToBoard(int gameArray[3][3], int a, int b, int player)
```

now just write:

```
gameArray[x][y] = player;
```

and in main:

```
int board[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
```

The rest is OK. Important to know is that the compiler sees you using an array and passes it as a pointer to the function. The function receives a pointer to the board array and the compiler "knows what to do" when you index it as `[x][y]`.

Comment: also for the assignation, he could do `gameArray[x][y] = player;` instead

Comment: Note however that `sizeof(gameArray)` in function `addMoveToBoard` is the size of a pointer, whereas `sizeof(board)` is `9 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: Thanks mate, I thought it had to be a pointer, as you can tell I don't know to much C yet. Java is my main language so pointers are a pain for me atm.